# What is the complete definition of encroachment at a penalty kick

Tags: football, penalty-shot

In offside, the position of a player's body (rather than just a physical part of it e.g. foot) is used to determine the offence. In encroachment at a penalty kick, can a player that's leaning forward over the 18-yard line be used to determine the offence as it is in offside, or must it be physical i.e  the foot.